# Найти и заменить в строке заданное слово

Tags: c++, c, строки, visual-c++

Найти и заменить в строке заданное слово. Что искать и на что заменять определяется пользователем.

Нужно заменить все найденные слова.

Вот моя попытка:

```
    char str[1000];
    char str_fr[40];
    char str_zamina_na[40];

    gets_s(str_fr);
    gets_s(str_zamina_na);

    int len = strlen(str) - 1;
    int lend = strlen(str_fr);
    int lend_2 = strlen(str_zamina_na);

    char * s = strstr(str, str_fr);


    int l = 0, w = 0, zm = lend_2 - lend;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
    {
        if(str[i] == s[l])
        {
            l++;
            if (l == lend)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lend_2; i++) {
                        s[i] = str_zamina_na[w]; w++;

                }


            }

        }


    }
```

Заменяет не все найдены слова. Также если слово которое мы вставляем больше за то которое мы заменяем, первые буквы следующего слова теряются. Если слово меньше наоборот. Возможно нужно как-то удлинить строку.

Comment: С или С++? Если искомое слово стоит в середине другого слова, нужно его заменять или нет?

Comment: C з елементами C++. Да, заменять!

Comment: Если это С++, то использовали бы `std::string`. Там замена [довольно легко](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15372760/2752075) делается.

Comment: Да, я знаю. В том и дело что нужно не используя std::string.

Comment: Такие вопросы - в которых уточнения, что требуется, идут по мере ответов - надо закрывать...

Answer (score 1):

Ну, что-то в духе

```
char str[1000];  // Будем считать, что заведомо хватит, иначе слишком сложно :)
char from[40];
char to[40];

gets_s(str);
gets_s(from);
gets_s(to);

for(char * c = strstr(str,from); c; c = strstr(str,from))
{
    memmove(c+strlen(to),c+strlen(from),strlen(c+strlen(from))+1);
    memcpy(c,to,strlen(to));
}

cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но нужно сделать не используя эти функции. Все вручную.

Comment: Покажите это в вашем условии! Ну сколько можно - все время пишут, решаешь - и такое: нет, это нельзя!... Интересно, вы везде так? Наняли мастеров ремонт в квартире сделать, а потом - нет, цвет не тот, паркет не из того дерева... Кто заинтересован в том, чтоб получить ответ на вопрос - вы или я? Ну напишите эти функции, раз же плюнуть - что вы, реализацию `memmove` не в состоянии написать?

Comment: Да, не в состоянии. Я новичок.

Comment: @Р.Р. Поищите в гугле готовую реализацию.